# Java Swing - How to draw trail for specific objects while others get redrawn?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, particles

I am making a program that spawns a bunch of particles in a JPanel window and then redraws them every time they move (AKA all the old particle shapes get wiped and then redrawn). I have added the option to track specific particles and I want to draw a trail for all particles that are currently being tracked... but I have no idea how.

I am painting these particle shapes by overriding the paintComponent() function and as far as I understand (I am completely new to Swing) the repaint() function will ALWAYS wipe all drawn shapes in the JPanel and then repaint them. So how do I achieve what I want to do?

View (JPanel where shapes are painted):

```
package LabPck;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class View extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    Model m;
    Timer timer = new Timer(m.delay, this);
    static final double width = 687;
    static final double height = 568;
    static final double offset = 10;

    View(Model model){
        this.m = model;
        setBackground(Color.black);
        timer.start();
    }


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for(int i = 0; i < Particle.getAmount(); i++){
            g.setColor(m.particle.get(i).pColor);
            if(m.particle.get(i).isTracked){
                // What do I do here?!
            }
            else{
                g.fillRect((int)Math.round(m.particle.get(i).x), (int)Math.round(m.particle.get(i).y), 2, 2);
            }
        }

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getSource() == timer) {
            m.moveAll();
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Particle class:

```
package LabPck;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;


public class Particle {
    double x, y;
    public boolean isMoving;
    public boolean isTracked;
    public Color pColor;

    private static int counter = 0;

    public Particle(){
        this.x = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(275, 375+1);
        this.y = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(225, 325+1);
        this.isMoving = true;
        this.isTracked = false;
        this.pColor = Color.BLUE;
        counter++;
    }

    public Particle(double xs, double ys){
        this.x = xs;
        this.y = ys;
        this.isMoving = true;
        this.isTracked = false;
        this.pColor = Color.BLUE;
        counter++;
    }

    public static int getAmount(){
        return counter;
    }

    void randomMove(double L){

        if(isMoving){
            double dx = L*Math.cos(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(-(2*Math.PI), (2*Math.PI)));
            double dy = L*Math.sin(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(-(2*Math.PI), (2*Math.PI)));
            if((this.x += dx) < 0 || (this.x += dx) > View.width){
                this.x += -dx;  
            }
            else if((this.y += dy) < 0 || (this.y += dy) > View.height){
                this.y += -dy;
            }
            else{
                this.x += dx;
                this.y += dy;
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Model (the class that moves the particles):

```
package LabPck;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Model {
    List<Particle> particle = new ArrayList<Particle>();
    int[][] map = new int[1000][1000];
    static double L = 1;
    static int delay = 100;

    Model(){
        L = 1;
        for(int i=0; i<80000; i++){
            particle.add(new Particle());
        }

    }

    void moveAll(){
        for(int i = 0; i < particle.size(); i++){
            if(particle.get(i).x <= View.offset || particle.get(i).x >= View.width || particle.get(i).y <= View.offset || particle.get(i).y >= View.height){
                particle.get(i).isMoving = false;
                this.map[(int)particle.get(i).x][(int)particle.get(i).y] = 1;
            }
            else if(this.map[(int)particle.get(i).x-1][(int)particle.get(i).y] == 1 || this.map[(int)particle.get(i).x+1][(int)particle.get(i).y] == 1 || this.map[(int)particle.get(i).x][(int)particle.get(i).y-1] == 1 || this.map[(int)particle.get(i).x][(int)particle.get(i).y+1] == 1){
                particle.get(i).isMoving = false;
                this.map[(int)particle.get(i).x][(int)particle.get(i).y] = 1;
            }
            else{
                particle.get(i).randomMove(L);
            }
        }
    }

    void setL(double value){
        L = value;
    }

    void setTimestamp(int ms){
        delay = ms;
    }
}
```

Main class that creates the components and runs the program:

```
package LabPck;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

class BrownAnimation extends JFrame {

    BrownAnimation () {
        // Set frame layout
        setSize(800,600);
        setLocation(0, 0);
        setTitle("Particle Simulator");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Create swing components
        Model model = new Model();
        Manipulation manip = new Manipulation(model);
        View viewPanel = new View(model);
        TrackingFrame tF = new TrackingFrame(model, viewPanel);

        // Add swing components to content pane
        Container c = getContentPane();

        c.add(viewPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        c.add(manip, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                BrownAnimation f = new BrownAnimation();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) The general approach to solving this problem is to store a list structure of the particles that require tracking. The list should be the size the number of 'past positions' that need to be drawn. When adding a new position, remove the oldest. When painting, iterate the list and draw all positions in it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Do you mean that every particle that is being tracked should have a separate list (that stores every position they have visited) and these lists are in turn stored into another list? Or Am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: *"Do you mean that every particle that is being tracked should have a separate list"* Yes. Probably best kept as an attribute of the `Particle` class itself. *"that stores every position they have visited)"* No. If the idea is to paint the last 10 positions, you'd store up to 20 in the list, thereafter, remove one from the start, for every on added to the end. Given there are particles to be tracked, and other not to be tracked, I'd suggest a further attribute indicating the number that will be the size of the list. *"..and these lists are in turn stored into another list?"* Well, the ..

Comment: .. particle objects, yes. Once each particle in the list has its own list, and the number telling how big the list should be. You're set.

Comment: @AndrewThompson "No. If the idea is to paint the last 10 positions, you'd store up to 20 in the list, thereafter, remove one from the start, for every on added to the end.". So the list that saves the positions is essentially a Queue? Also why should this list be 20 long if I store the last 10 positions? Is it the X and Y value? Because a position of X and Y can be represented as a array (with a size of 2), and I assume that a Queue can hold an array as an element?... or?

Comment: *"If the idea is to paint the last 10 positions, you'd store up to 20 in the list"* Oops! I meant to write.. *"If the idea is to paint the last **20** positions, you'd store up to 20 in the list"* (Curse my sloppy typing.) *"Is it the X and Y value?"* No. 20 list entries of 20 **`Point` objects** would make more sense. One thing I was trying to get across was **Object** Oriented Programming and encapsulation The encapsulation would be seen in each `Particle` encapsulating a list of its own positions. The OOP would be in using a `Point` instead of separate `x` and `y` attributes for positions.